# How to use \lastnamedcs?

Tags: macros, luatex, dimensions

Please look at this short MWE:

```
% Plain LuaTeX
\ifcsname b@selineskip\endcsname
\else
\expandafter\newdimen\lastnamedcs
\lastnamedcs\normalbaselineskip
\fi

\expandafter\the\csname b@selineskip\endcsname

\bye
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\ifcsname` does not define a csname for undefined names (unlike `\csname`) so

```
\ifcsname foo\endcsname\else
\expandafter\show\lastnamedcs
\fi



\bye
```

produces

```
> \^^@=undefined.
<recently read> \IMPOSSIBLE.
            
l.2 \expandafter\show\lastnamedcs
```

it is generating an internal inaccessible token that isn't usable with `\newdimen` (or anything).

A perhaos simpler to understand variant is

```
\ifcsname foo\endcsname\else
\expandafter\def\expandafter\z\expandafter{\lastnamedcs}
\show\z
\fi



\bye
```

which has terminal output

```
> \z=macro:
->\IMPOSSIBLE..
l.3 \show\z
```

Comment: OK, I missunderstood `\lastnamedcs` completly.